# collapsible nav bootstrap not working on phones

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a website using bootstrap to make a portfolio website. The website link is http://mrmillerphotography.surge.sh/ and the mobile navigation works when resizing the window on chrome and firefox but it does not work when accessing the website from my iphone. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to add the 'viewport' meta tag.

In the <head>, add: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">